# React-Highcharts does not redraw chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, highcharts, meteor-react

My code uses `ultimatejs:tracker-react` and `react-highcharts` to draw a chart using live data pulled from a Mongodb collection. For simplicity, `autopublish` package is enabled.

**Problem:** After setting the initial data series for Highcharts, `chart.series[0].setData([5,4,3,2,1])` updates the series but the new data is not drawn on the chart. Chart still shows the initial 3 points Highcharts was initialized with.

How can we get the new `series` values be drawn on the highcharts chart?

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts';

import { Pressure } from '../api/pressure.js';


export class PressureChart extends TrackerReact(Component) {

    // Returns data in the Highcharts series format
    seriesData() {
        const result = Pressure.find().fetch();
        pressure = _.pluck(result, 'pressure');
        pressure = pressure.map(p => Number(p))
        time = _.pluck(result, 'timestamp');
        series = _.zip(time, pressure);
        return pressure
    }

    updateChart() {
        let chart = this.refs.chart.getChart()
        console.log(chart.series[0].data)       // Echos out an array of 3 elements
        chart.series[0].setData([5,4,3,2,1])    // Tests using this array, instead of array pulled from Collection
        console.log(chart.series[0].data)       // Echos out an array of 5 elements
    }

    render() {
        const config = {
            series: [{
                data: [1,2,3]
            }]
        };

        if(this.seriesData().length){
            this.updateChart()
        }

        return (
            <ReactHighcharts config={config} ref="chart"></ReactHighcharts>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to call `chart.redraw()` explicitly?

Comment: @Khang yes, I called `chart.redraw()` right after `.setData()`. That did not redraw the chart. Strange.....

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure out the problem. This is this package use to render the chart:

```
renderChart: function (config){
  if (!config) {
    throw new Error('Config must be specified for the ' + displayName + ' component');
  }
  let chartConfig = config.chart;
  this.chart = new Highcharts[chartType]({
    ...config,
    chart: {
      ...chartConfig,
      renderTo: this.refs.chart
    }
  }, this.props.callback);

  if (!this.props.neverReflow) {
    win.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
      this.chart && this.chart.options && this.chart.reflow();
    });
  }
},

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.neverReflow || (nextProps.isPureConfig && this.props.config === nextProps.config)) {
    return true;
  }
  this.renderChart(nextProps.config);
  return false;
},

getChart: function (){
  if (!this.chart) {
    throw new Error('getChart() should not be called before the component is mounted');
  }
  return this.chart;
},

componentDidMount: function (){
  this.renderChart(this.props.config);
},
```

ref: https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts/blob/master/src/chartsFactory.jsx#L22-L59

As you can see, every time the chart need to be drawn/updated, the package will create a new chart and place it on the screen. In your code you use the update chart function in the render function, so this is what happens:

- First render: the chart, call this `chart1`, is rendered normally because if statement if false
- Second render: if is true, code inside get executed, `chart1` is updated. But it does not stop there, React keeps rendering, ReactHighCharts create a new chart instance (`chart2`) with the old config and place it on this screen. This `chart2` replaces `chart1`, so you never see the updated chart.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the problem! Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: IMO, it is more like a bug.

Comment: Their example shows using `chart.series[0].addPoint({x: 10, y: 12});` to add a point. If the chart is to be updated whenever a new result is found in the Mongodb query used to populate the chart, where in the React component do we create `cursor.observeChanges`, and do we destroy this observer in `componentWillUnmount`?

Comment: Not sure I am understand you. Did you want to know how to get latest data in Mongodb to populate the chart?

Comment: Yes thats right... the chart should continue to update as more data is added to mongodb.

Comment: As you can see in code above , `renderChart` function, a new chart will be created and put on the screen instead of updating the current chart when data changes

Comment: is there any fix for this issue guys?